# AS3 how to inject framescript and get a reference to the mc the script was injected into

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was wondering wether it is possible to inject a frame script into a MovieClip and to get a reference to the mc the script was injected into from the function used as the frame script.

A simple working example is this:

There is a MovieClip named mc. It has a frame label 'end' somewhere and we want to add a stop() to that frame without adding code to the MovieClip itself (keep in mind that this is just an example). So here is the code (we could place it on the main time line of a test movie that has the mc on the stage):

```
var end:int=0;
for (var i:int=0;i<mc.currentLabels.length;i++)
{
    if (mc.currentLabels[i].name=='end') 
        end=mc.currentLabels[i].frame;
}
function doStop():void{
    mc.stop();
}
// Frame script for label 'end'
mc.addFrameScript(end-1,doStop); // Frames are 0-based here
```

When the playhead reaches the frame labeled "end" in mc the function doStop() will execute. This function keeps its original scope however. So to stop the mc we need to specify mc.stop(). 'this' points to the object where the function doStop resides so this.stop() won't work. If we wanted to use the same function for multiple mcs we'd have to get a reference to the currently targeted mc somehow. So that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a reference to mc clip :

```
function doStop(target : MovieClip):Function{
    return function():void
    {
        target.stop();
    }
}
// Frame script for label 'end'
mc.addFrameScript(end-1,doStop(mc)); // Frames are 0-based here
```

Comment: Yes, splendid. That does work. Thank you for pointing out this approach.